# R function that drops columns according column value and primary keys?

Tags: r

Currently I have a compiled data frame, so for the same item code there are fixed and changing variables. For example:

..primary key..b......    c.   
 
1. 1234........apple ..pear
2. 1234........apple ..orange
3. 5678........berry .. lime
4. 5679........orange.apple
5. 5679........orange.apple

In this case, since column c has different variables for both line1 and line2 despite having the same primary key #1234, column c should be dropped.
Is there any way i can do this without hard coding the column names?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can find the columns that need to be dropped using `summarize_all()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(key = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
            b = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"),
            c = c("p", "o", "l", "a", "a"))

drop_cols <- df %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  summarize_all(~ any(. != .[1])) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  select_if(any) %>%
  colnames()

df %>% select(- one_of(drop_cols))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with `dplyr` is for each `primary` key count number of distinct elements in each column. We then `select` columns where there is only one unique value for each `primary` key.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(df %>%
          group_by(primary) %>%
          mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), n_distinct) %>%
          select_if(~all(. == 1)) %>% 
          names)

#   primary      b
#1    1234  apple
#2    1234  apple
#3    5678  berry
#4    5679 orange
#5    5679 orange
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(primary = c(1234L, 1234L, 5678L, 5679L, 5679L), 
b = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("apple", 
"berry", "orange"), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("apple", "lime", "orange", "pear"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```